# How to use admin.ModelAdmin to customize the "add" popup?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

The story begins with 2 models (`User` and `ClientAccount`) which are linked with an extra M2M model.

It is possible to create `ClientAccount` during editing `User`. The page will show a popup which allow you create a new `ClientAccount`. But the problem is: can I disable the foreign key fields of `ClientAccount` which is linking to `User`? This is quite confusing.

[image: Description]

Code here:

```
class User(models.Model):
    client_accounts = models.ManyToManyField('ClientAccount', related_name='+', through='UserClientAccountM2M', through_fields=('user', 'client_account'))

class ClientAccount(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField('User', related_name='+', through='UserClientAccountM2M', through_fields=('client_account', 'user'))

class UserClientAccountM2M(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='user_id')
    client_account = models.ForeignKey(ClientAccount, db_column='client_id')

class UserAdmin(TimeLimitedAdmin):
    class ClientAccountInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = ClientAccount.users.through
    inlines = [
        ClientAccountInline,
    ]

class ClientAccountAdmin(TimeLimitedAdmin):
    class UserInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = ClientAccount.users.through
    inlines = [
        UserInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: Can you give some code?
The current code of your admin.py?
Normally the m2m fields are not part of the default admin view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realise this is an old question, but I came across it as the most relevant question whilst looking to solve a similar problem (hide a FK inline only in the add popup). I'm sure you have left this problem well behind by now, but maybe others will find it useful.

I added the below to the `ModelAdmin` class that the popup is for. I check the `request` for the `GET` params only present when the popup dialog is launched, and if they are there, I loop through the inlines and remove the one I don't want.

```
def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
    inline_instances = super().get_inline_instances(request, obj=None)
    if '_to_field' in request.GET and '_popup' in request.GET:
        # Popup dialog is open.
        unwanted_inline = None
        for inline in inline_instances:
            inline_model_name = inline.opts.model.__name__
            if inline_model_name == 'UnwantedModelName':
                unwanted_inline = inline
        if unwanted_inline:
            inline_instances.remove(unwanted_inline)
    return inline_instances
```

In your case, I would add the above to `ClientAccountAdmin`, removing the `UserInline`.

Comment: You reminded me what I was doing 5 years ago. Lots of things happened LOL I don't write Django anymore but it seems your answer is correct. Thank you anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to hide the m2m fields in the ClientAccount you can remove the line in the Admin.py

because there you explicitely say it should show the connection to the user in a tabularInline:

```
class ClientAccountAdmin(TimeLimitedAdmin):
    class UserInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = ClientAccount.users.through
    #inlines = [UserInline,]
```

There you say explicitely you want to have the M2M field from ClientAccount to User in an Inline, which you do not want. Get rid of it and the fields will disappear

EDIT:
The problem is that the "add..." link will always refer to the `.../ClientAccount/add/?_popup=1` page which uses the default admin view for this model.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But vice versa, the user should be able to create `User` while editing `ClientAccount`. I am afraid your answer will disable this action.